# What's the best "type renaming" method?

Tags: c++, typedef, user-defined-types, preprocessor-directive

If I wanted to rename the `std::string` type to a simpler and more naturally looking `string`, which of these two methods should I use (based on performance and what is usually the standard)

Should I rename it as a preprocessed directive

```
#define string std::string
```

Or do it with a type definition

```
typedef std::string string;
```

What's the most performant method? What is also more familiar and recognized to the community?

Comment: If you wanna 'rename' `std::string` into `string`, write `using std::string` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: No matter how you do it - performance will not be affected. Unless you talk about compile time performance ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick answer, I'm still pretty noob at this.

Comment: The #define my lead to funny compiler and linker errors (in libraries)

Comment: `#define string std::string` will get you laughed out of the room

Comment: @M.M y u so tragical lol.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just

```
using std::string;
```

---

If you want a slightly different name, e.g.

```
using String = std::string;
```

---

Avoid macros, they don't respect scopes and are generally Evil™.

For example, the proposed macro

```
#define string std::string
```

… yields formal Undefined Behavior if you include any standard library header, because it defines a name used by the standard library.

**C++11 §17.6.4.2.2/1** [macro.names]:

> **”** A translation unit that includes a standard library header shall not `#define` or `#undef` names declared in any standard library header.

Comment: Like the bit about discouraging use of macros.

Comment: Thanks! I added a little more info. ;-)

Comment: That `§17.6.4.2.2/1` is a good reason not to define any lowercase_only (with/without underscores) +1

Comment: Plus one: especially for the bit about UB.

Answer (score 5):

Writing

```
using std::string;
```

is the best way. That has the effect of bringing the standard c++ library string class into the current namespace.

But really you should learn to read code that contains scope resolution operators fluently. In writing

```
std::string
```

folk reading your code know exactly what is going on.

Comment: I know that the practice of writing namespace qualifications, in particular `std::`, has been adopted into some coding guidelines. And many programmers from such companies/projects have claimed that they find it *easier* to read the code with the qualifications, after a period getting used to it. However since it's more to write and more to read and parse (both of which takes time), and since a modern IDE will tell you the definition of anything, I suspect that much valuable programmers' time is lost because of this practice.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, since close to 80% of developers' time is spent on code maintenance, IMO the extra time spent on explicitly using `std::` pales in comparison to the overall cost of a project.

Comment: @RSahu: Well the 80% is my (unmentioned) argument, except I draw the opposite conclusion: I think the time spent on making the code readable and clear, pays for itself over and over again during maintenance.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, different strokes for different folks. I find it more readable with the `std::` prefix.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `using` if you only want not to write namespace

```
using std::string;
```

Neither will be more performant since all of them are compile time.

For more complex cases you may use other form of `using`

```
using short_name = complex_name<possibly, with, templates>;
```